# How to use two cuda cards and nsight Eclipse on a Mac

Tags: macos, cuda, nsight

I finally have two nvidia cards in my Mac so that I can use Nsight Eclipse to debug CUDA code.
But clearly I have not configured things properly because I only get a breakpoint into assembler, and then my Mac hangs if I continue. I think it is trying to run the CUDA program on the card used by the display, rather than the other card. I also get  messages that it cannot find the symbols.

So how do I set things up properly?
Thanks,
Jim

Answer (score 1):

perhaps the easiest solution might be to use the `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` environment variable which is described [here](http://www.resultsovercoffee.com/2011/02/cudavisibledevices.html)  Declare it in the session before you launch nsight EE, and that should be sufficient.  You will have to experiment with it to find the right "mask" to select the GPU of interest.

The symbol messages are a different issue, I think.  Are you trying to debug the debug project in nsight eclipse?  That should create the symbols for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can select the device to use for debugging in Nsight preferences. You can also set it for the debug configuration. 
Note that Nsight also honours CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES variable Robert mentioned.